# ssh using sshpass in python seems to not work

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a python script which is supposed to ssh in to a client and execute a bash from the client. As a test scenario I am using just 1 machine to connect but the objective is to connect to several clients and execute bash scripts from those machines.

My Python code:

```
 import os 
 import subprocess
 import time


def ssh_login_execute():
    if device['PWD'] != "":
            run=('sshpass -p %s ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t -p %s %s@%s' % (device['PWD'], device['PORT'], device['USER'], device['IP']))
    else:
            run=('ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t -p %s %s@%s' % (device['PORT'], device['USER'], device['IP']))

    cmd = ('cd %s' % (script_path))

    run2=run.split()
    run2.append(cmd)
    t=subprocess.Popen(run2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
    print "I am in 192.168.1.97"
    execute_tg()
    return t

def execute_tg():
   path = "/home/"
   os.chdir(path)
   print os.getcwd()
   cmd=("sh my_script.sh")
   t=subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    device = {}
    device['PORT']=22
    device['PWD']= "abcd"
    device['USER']= "root"
    device['IP']= "192.168.1.97"
    script_path= "/home/"
    ssh_login_execute()
```

On running the code "python script.py", I see output as:

```
  I am in 192.168.1.97
  /home/
  Output is sh: 0: Can't open my_script.sh
```

Although the "my_script.sh" is in /home directory in 192.168.1.97.
How do I get rid of this issue and at the same time make it scalable to ssh to multiple clients and execute bash.

Comment: try to use paramiko to ssh in and execute a command.

Comment: when we do "pxssh.pxssh.login('hostname', ''username', 'password')". is there a way to ssh in simultaneously to 5 systems. Probably I need to create a list of hoistname, uisername and password and traverse through them. Any good idea if you have, will be appreciated.

Comment: pxssh or pexpect works fine, for now, for 1 system. Just need to gt that going with multiple ssh clients. With the previous method I don't think it was ssh'ing to the specified IP as I changed the path name and see that it was going to the location specified in the host but not on client.

Comment: when it prints /home/ you are in your /home/@localhost not /home/@192.168.1.97

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script `my_script.sh` is probably not in `/home/` as expected in the code.

```
   path = "/home/"
   os.chdir(path)
   print os.getcwd()
   cmd=("sh my_script.sh")
```

Also it should print the current directory as well with `print os.getcwd()`. You should change those values based on the real location of your script.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part on the output. It does print /home on os.getcwd() , but I am not sure whether ssh is successful. Although print does get executed, means sshpass went in without any issue. While checking the process "ps -ef | grep sshpass" I dont see any "sshpass" session, which makes me think that there is a hidden issue somewhere.

Comment: when you are calling `sh my_script` that is executing on your local machine ... you need to use a ssh library (like paramiko ssh)

Comment: But wont it successfully connect to a client using sshpass and execute , "sh myscript.sh" on the client.?

Comment: @learning It would run myscript.sh on the client and not on the remote server. Even the process spawned with `run2` is running on the client even though it's interacting with the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example utilizing the paramiko module and using the getpass module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import paramiko
import getpass
class Remote():
    def __init__(self, hostfile, username, commands):
        self.hostfile = hostfile
        self.username = username
        self.commands = commands
    def execute(self):
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        ##########################################################
        # just in case it does not recognize the known_host keys
        # in the known_hosts file
        ##########################################################
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
        for i in self.hostfile.readlines():
            print("Connecting to..." + i)
            client.connect(i.strip(), 22, self.username, self.password)
            stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(self.commands)
            for t in stdout.readlines():
                print(t.strip())
            for t in stderr.readlines():
                print(t.strip())
#--------------------------------------------------------
commands="""
echo "##################################################";
hostname;
echo "##################################################";
uname -a;
echo "##################################################";
dmidecode -t bios
"""
#---------------------------------------------------------
username = raw_input("Username: ")
hostfile = open('hosts')
a = Remote(hostfile, username, commands)
a.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "home" directory is usually something like `/home/<username>` or perhaps `/users/<username>`.  In general shells will generally accept `~` as a synonym for the path to your home directory.  Does this work instead:

```
cmd=("sh ~/my_script.sh")
```

Comment: his problem is that he is calling `sh myscript` on the local system ... where it doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

Actually sshpass executes ssh command/connection in a single go. Once the remote query is executed through subprocess.Popen() your program control will be back to local machine in the next line. And your program will give error "Can't open my_script.sh" because your script is not on local machine whereas it is on remote machine.

My suggestion is to make the full sshpass command with what to execute in a single program varibale (in your case 'run2' variable) and pass it to subprocess.Popen() in single go. Modified code is as below:

```
import os 
import subprocess
import time

def ssh_login_execute():
    if device['PWD'] != "":
        run=('sshpass -p %s ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t -p %s %s@%s' % (device['PWD'], device['PORT'], device['USER'], device['IP']))
    else:
        run=('ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t -p %s %s@%s' % (device['PORT'], device['USER'], device['IP']))

    cmd = ('sh /%s/%s' % (script_path,'my_script.sh'))

    run2=run.split()
    run2.append(cmd)
    t=subprocess.Popen(run2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
    print "I am in 192.168.1.97" # HERE YOU ASSUMED THAT YOU ARE IN REMOTE MACHINE BUT ACTUALLY YOU ARE IN LOCAL MACHINE ONLY
    return t

if __name__ == "__main__":
    device = {}
    device['PORT']=22
    device['PWD']= "abcd"
    device['USER']= "root"
    device['IP']= "192.168.1.97"
    script_path= "/home/"
    ssh_login_execute()
```

Comment: Please notice comment in the line below in modified code for better underderstanding                                                                                                                      print "I am in 192.168.1.97" # HERE YOU ASSUMED THAT YOU ARE IN REMOTE MACHINE BUT ACTUALLY YOU ARE IN LOCAL MACHINE ONLY